# Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error

Tags: php, jpeg

```
Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(): gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error: in C:\OpenServer\domains\site\inc\account.inc.php on line 91
```

Присутствует вот такая ошибка. В чём проблема? Как устранить?

Сам код:

```
if ($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name']) {
        if ($_FILES['avatar']['type'] != 'image/jpeg')
            messageSend('error', 'Неверный тип изображения.');
        if ($_FILES['avatar']['size'] > 30000)
            messageSend('error', 'Размер изображения слишком большой.');

        $Image = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name']);
        $Size = getimagesize($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name']);
        $Tmp = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 100);
        imagecopyresampled($Tmp, $Image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100, $Size[0], $Size[1]);

        if ($_SESSION['USER_AVATAR'] == 0) {
            $Files = glob('img/avatar/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
            foreach ($Files as $Num => $Dir) {
                $Num++;
                $Count = sizeof(glob($Dir.'/*.*'));
                if ($Count < 250) {
                    $Download = $Dir.'/'.$_SESSION['USER_ID'];
                    $_SESSION['USER_AVATAR'] = $Num;
                    mysqli_query($CONNECT, "UPDATE users SET avatar = $Num WHERE id = $_SESSION[USER_ID]");
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else
            $Download = 'img/avatar/'.$_SESSION['USER_AVATAR'].'/'.$_SESSION['USER_ID'];

        imagejpeg($Tmp, $Download.'.jpg');
        imagedestroy($Image);
        imagedestroy($Tmp);
    }
```

Магия в том что imagecreatefrompng() работает. Объясните дураку что не так? И если это говнокод то подскажите как реализовать задумку правильнее.

Comment: тут два варианта либо картинка битая, либо картинка битая

Comment: @Naumov Я проверял на разных картинках формата .jpg

Comment: До этого какие notice ещё выводяться?

Comment: @Naumov Нет, не выводятся.